# How to combine multiple matching rows into one row?

Tags: sql, grouping

So I have a table that looks like this in SQL:

```
Unique ID   Total Paid
    1           50
    1           40
    2           40
    2           60
    1           50
    2           40
    3           0
    3           50
    3           40
```

I want to be able to make the Unique ID column just one row, and create multiple columns for each Total Paid, like this:

```
Unique ID   Total Paid 1    Total Paid 2    Total Paid 3
    1           50              40              50
    2           40              60              40
    3           0               50              40
```

I've looked around a little, saw keywords such as pivot, unpivot, dense_rank but I'm not sure if these are applicable to my problem. Can someone suggest how I can go about doing this?

Thanks

Bonus: Also in the case there might be more than 3 of the same unique ID, what can I do?

Comment: what is your rdbms?? and you need `PIVOT` just google for some examples for your rdbms. But you need a field to order your data and identify who is `Total Paid 1` sql set doesnt have an intrinsic order unless you use `ORDER BY`

Comment: If there are more than 3 you can do what ever you want you are the one who set the expected output. EX: show more columns, show the TOP 3 biggest/smaller values.

Comment: Do you have a hard limit on the number of Total Paid's or can it be any number? If you have a hard limit ... and it's a reasonable amount to type you could get away with conditional aggregation. You could also pivot. If it can be any number you'll have to do dynamic pivoting ... which usually requires dynamic SQL.